# iTunes Library "Distinguished Kind"

Tags: ios, xml, itunes

I'm parsing iTunes xml library.
Since iTunes 12 new playlists are available (TV Show, PDF, ...)

I would like to filter some of this playlists thanks to the "Distinguished Kind" key value.

Unfortunately these keys doesn't match the documented [ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/ITLibPlaylist_reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKind)

Where are documented these "Distinguished Kind" values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at an `iTunes Music Library.xml` file that was written with iTunes 12 and the `Distinguished Kind` keys do match the Apple documentation for [`ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKind`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/ITLibPlaylist_reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKind) but they are offset by one. The enum is a zero-based index but the XML appears to be a one-based index. Subtracting 1 from the value in `Distinguished Kind` results in a correct match for all of my playlists.

For example, given the XML entry for my "TV Shows" playlist:

```
<dict>
    <key>Name</key><string>TV Shows</string>
    <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>117297</integer>
    <key>Distinguished Kind</key><integer>3</integer>
    <key>TV Shows</key><true/>
    <key>All Items</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Matches `ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKindTVShows` from the `ITLibDistinguishedPlaylistKind` enum.

Comment: Lot of "Distinguished Kind" are missing but it's a good hint.